# beginning and ending sign in regular expression in python

Tags: python, regex

`'[A-Za-z0-9-_]*'`

`'^[A-Za-z0-9-_]*$'`

I want to check if a string only contains the sign in the above expression, just want to make sure no more weird sign like `#%&/()` are in the strings.

I am wondering if there's any difference between these two regular expression? Did the beginning and ending sign matter? Will it affect the result somehow?

Comment: When inside of []s, it's best to put the '-' character, when used to match the character '-', at the end of the [], as in [A-Za-z0-9_-]. Otherwise it's possible to misread your form as "9 to underscore" before seeing that it's actually '0 to 9, -, and _'. It also sometimes happens that people change, say, 'A-C-_' to 'ABC-_' and forget that changing the first - affects how the second is interpreted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The beginning and end sign match the beginning and end of a String.

The first will match any String that contains zero or more ocurrences of the class [A-Za-z0-9-_] (basically any string whatsoever...).

The second will match an empty String, but not one that contains characters not defined in [A-Za-z0-9-_]

Answer (score 3):

Python regular expressions are anchored at the beginning of strings (like in many other languages): hence the `^` sign at the beginning doesn’t make any difference.  However, the `$` sign does very much make one: if you don’t include it, you’re only going to match the beginning of your string, and the end could contain anything – including the characters you want to exclude.  Just try `re.match("[a-z0-9]", "abcdef/%&")`.

In addition to that, you may want to use a regular expression that simply excludes the characters you’re testing for, it’s much safe (hence `[^#%&/()]` – or maybe you have to do something to escape the parentheses; can’t remember how it works at the moment).

Comment: Python offers two match methods, `match` and `search` - make sure you use the right one, as search is not anchored.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will. A regex can match anywhere in its input. `#` *will* match in your first regex.